# How do I get the JSON data to return?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I want to bring data from another table to use in detail view. But the value returned from the getData method is null. What should i do ?

```
<th data-field="id" data-detail-formatter="DetailFormatter">ID</th>
<th data-field="prefix" data-detail-formatter="DetailFormatter">Prefix</th>
<th data-field="fname" data-detail-formatter="DetailFormatter"Name</th>

function DetailFormatter(index, row) {
   return '<p> ID: ' + row.id + '</p>',
          '<p> Name: ' + row.prefix + '</p>',
          '<p> Price: ' + row.fname + '</p>',
          '<p> Degree: ' + getData() + '</p>'
}

function getData() {
   var data

   $.getScript('http://localhost:55289/ManageTeacher/GetTacherDegree', function (script, status, jqxhr) {
      data = script
   });

   return data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a kind of asynchronous process. You are able to get correct value inside callback function. So you can move the codes that handles `data` inside callback function instead of returning `data`.

```
function getData() {
   var data

   $.getScript('http://localhost:55289/ManageTeacher/GetTacherDegree', function (script, status, jqxhr) {
      data = script.  // <--------------- right place
   });

   return data // <------------------- wrong place
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, sorry :(

Comment: you have to write the code inside the callback. outside of it, you are not able to get correct data. outside of it, it is always undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try using fetch api inside an async function

```
async function getData() {

const data = await fetch('http://localhost:55289/ManageTeacher/GetTacherDegree')
.then(res => res.json())

 return data
 }
```

Comment: How do I get an object promise value?